# rails generate uses wrong version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I am developing a Rails app using RVM.  I have the following in `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.4'
#ruby-gemset=mpclub_4_1

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
```

`rails s` works fine and gives the following:

```
[2014-12-30 15:14:47] INFO  ruby 2.1.4 (2014-10-27) [x86_64-linux]
```

`ruby -v` gives:

```
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux]
```

However, `rails generate model Download` gives:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4
```

My question is:  How do I run the `rails generate` command?  Where is ruby 2.1.2 coming from?  Any help troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting your ruby version using rvm like so? `rvm use ruby-version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the file in `which rails` is picking ruby from the correct ruby location. Sometimes it might be pointing to the default ruby installation i.e /usr/bin/ruby rather than the rvm installation of ruby.

I personally use [rbenv](http://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)(in case you wanna try out an alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Just tell rvm which version of ruby

`which ruby`

then

`rvm use ruby-2.3.1`